The answer is not single
This is part 3, see for part 2: The answer is not ___

If the answer is not single, then what is the answer?



4th
2nd
3rd
3rd
3rd
2nd














The items are

 mousepad, dinosaur, handcuffs, lightbulb, calculator referee.


 By indexing the letters shown by the numbers above the items you get mou(s)epad, d(i)nosaur, ha(n)dcuffs, li(g)htbulb, ca(l)culator r(e)feree and so SINGLE!


 Doubling the numbers and then doing the same thing you get mousepa(d), din(o)saur, handc(u)ffs, light(b)ulb, calcu(l)ator ref(e)ree and so DOUBLE! Which is the answer we are looking for.


I was in the middle of writing my answer... Well, there's no need to finish it now

Yeah it happens got sniped like a million times here personally.
